# Import views file from app into project urls unresolved

Tags: django

I'm trying to import `grader/grader/core/views.py` into `grader/grader/urls.py` but get unresolved reference. I have tried several import statements but haven't found any that get's resolved. What is the correct way to import?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do the imports work when you do `python manage.py shell` and run them in the shell?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the folder that contains manage.py, then scroll down to

'**mark directory as**', then click on **Sources Root**. That solves the problem in Pycharm IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `grader/grader` is on the Python path.

Therefore you would import views.py from `grader/grader/cores` with:

```
from core import views
```

Comment: That also gets unresolved. I've added another screen shot to my original question

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing the Python interpreter from 2.7 to 3.5